# Converting a number into tetradecimal/ASCII

Tags: assembly, x86-64

[Assembly x86-64]

Specifically, I am trying to convert 137,799 to a tetradecimal and then into an ASCII value, that should be "3830B" but I am getting "3830;", so my last digit is wrong for some reason. Here's my code:

```
; Part 1 - Successive division

mov eax, dword [iNum1] ; get the integer 137,799
mov rcx, 0 ; digitCount = 0
mov ebp, 14 ; set for dividing by 14

divideLoop:
            mov edx, 0
            div ebp ; divide by 14

            push rdx ; push remainder
            inc rcx

            cmp eax, 0 
            jne divideLoop
; -----
; Part 2 - Convert remainders and store

mov rbx, num1String ; get addr of string
mov rsi, 0 ; index = 0 

popLoop:
        pop r8
        add r8b, "0" ; converting to ASCII

        mov byte [rbx+rsi], r8b
        inc rsi
        loop popLoop    

mov byte [rbx+rsi], NULL
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the ASCII table. The letters A, B, C... do **not** follow directly after 9.

Comment: Note that `loop` is inefficient (but maybe won't slow down any more than `div`), and you don't need to push/pop.  Just start from the end of a buffer.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for a simple base-10 function (where you can drop in a table lookup instead of `add edx, '0'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is adding the number you got to the letter '0':

```
    add r8b, "0" ; converting to ASCII
```

This works for digits, as `0` to `9` are contiguous in ASCII, but after the digits there are some symbols before the alphabet starts. Take a look at this table:

https://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm

The easiest way is to add a lookup-table in your program ("0123456789AB") and then use the number you got to index the correct character.

```
table: .string "0123456789AB"
// ...
mov r8b, [table+r8b]
```

Comment: Note that `symbol + register` only works in position-dependent code on systems where symbols are in the low 32 bits of address space (e.g. Linux but not OS X).  But yes, a digit table lookup is a good way to do conversions to bases higher than 10.  In PIE / PIC code, you'd want the table base address in a register from a RIP-relative LEA, but using the table base right in the addressing mode is good when it's usable.